# ADF shared application modules

Tags: oracle-adf

Is it possible to nest application modules of different scopes such as shared,session, user within the same root application module?

I have done this but I think it causes blocked threads and affects performance

Answer (score 0):

When nesting application modules always set the property

jbo.shared.txn

To a value in the root application module otherwise you will get thread blocking issues under high load. This will allow to nest shared and session scoped AMs as well.